# How to passively capture from Unix domain sockets (AF_UNIX socket monitoring)?

Tags: linux, debugging, unix-sockets, pcap

TCP/IP and UDP captures can be made using `tcpdump`/`dumpcap` and produces a pcap/pcapng file which can be fed to Wireshark for further analysis. Does a similar tool exist for named Unix domain sockets? (A general solution that works for abstract sockets would be nice too though.)

`strace` as-is is not sufficient, it is not straightforward to filter for Unix domain sockets I/O. A [proxy using `socat` or alike](https://superuser.com/q/484671/47108) is also not suitable as the goal is passive analysis for existing open programs.

How can I obtain a packet capture that I can use in Wireshark for analysis? Example protocol applications are X11 (Xorg, my current application) and cURL/PHP (HTTP). I have seen a [`CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/UNIX_DIAG.html) option in the Linux kernel, is this of some use?

Comment: See [Capture the X11 protocol's traffic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192005)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks, but since Xorg was started with `-nolisten tcp`, there is no TCP socket. If all fails, then I will probably revert to using xscope or your neat strace+text2pcap trick. I would still be interested in a generic Unix socket capture though (for just data, not side-channel data).

Comment: Beside strace, you can also look at auditd and systemtap.

Comment: [systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/WSunixSockets) almost looks like a GDB hack, but then at kernel level. Don't know about audit, I only found a LSM hook that checked whether you are allowed to read/write. (I am currently digging in the Linux kernel source code)

Comment: socat + tcpdump works perfect for me. See https://superuser.com/a/1421184/1556070.

Answer (score 25):

As of Linux kernel v4.2-rc5 it is not possible to capture directly using the interfaces that are in use by libpcap. libpcap uses the Linux-specific [`AF_PACKET`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/packet.7.html) (alias `PF_PACKET`) domain which only allows you to capture data for data going through a "[netdevice](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netdevice.7.html)" (such as Ethernet interfaces).

There is no kernel interface for capturing from `AF_UNIX` sockets. Standard Ethernet captures have an Ethernet header with source/destination, etc. Unix sockets have no such fake header and the [link-layer header types registry](http://www.tcpdump.org/linktypes.html) does not list anything related to this.

The basic entry points for data are [`unix_stream_recvmsg`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/unix/af_unix.c?h=v4.2-rc5#n2208) and [`unix_stream_sendmsg`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/unix/af_unix.c?h=v4.2-rc5#n1636) for `SOCK_STREAM` (`SOCK_DGRAM` and `SOCK_SEQPACKET` have similarly named functions). Data is buffered in `sk->sk_receive_queue` and in the [`unix_stream_sendmsg` function](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/unix/af_unix.c?h=v4.2-rc5#n1715), there is no code that ultimately lead into calling the [`tpacket_rcv` function](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/packet/af_packet.c?h=v4.2-rc5#n1960) for packet captures. See [this analysis by osgx on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22118477/427545) for more details on the internals of packet capture in general.

Back to the original question on `AF_UNIX` socket monitoring, if you are mainly interested in application data, you have some options:

- Passive (also works for already running processes):

  - Use `strace` and capture on possible system calls that perform I/O. There are lots of them, `read`, `pread64`, `readv`, `preadv`, `recvmsg` and many more... See [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192011/8250) example for `xterm`. Disadvantage of this approach is that you first have to find your file descriptor and then still might miss out system calls. With strace you can use `-e trace=file` for most of them (`pread` is only covered by `-e trace=desc`, but it probably not used for Unix sockets by most of the programs).
  - Break on/modify `unix_stream_recvmsg`, `unix_stream_sendmsg` (or `unix_dgram_*` or `unix_seqpacket_*`) in the **kernel** and output the data, somewhere. You can use SystemTap for setting such trace points, here is [an example](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/wiki/WSunixSockets) to monitor for outgoing messages. Requires [kernel support and availability of debugging symbols](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SystemTap).
- Active (only works for new processes):

  - Use a proxy that also writes files. You could write a quick multiplexer yourself or hack something like this that also outputs a pcap (beware of the limitations, for example `AF_UNIX` can pass file descriptors, `AF_INET` cannot):

    ```
    # fake TCP server connects to real Unix socket
    socat TCP-LISTEN:6000,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:some.sock
    # start packet capture on said port
    tcpdump -i lo -f 'tcp port 6000'
    # clients connect to this Unix socket
    socat UNIX-LISTEN:fake.sock,fork TCP-CONNECT:127.0.0.1:6000
    ```
  - Use a dedicated application proxy. For X11, there is xscope ([git](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/xorg/app/xscope/), [manual](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/xscope.1.xhtml)).

The suggested `CONFIG_UNIX_DIAG` option is unfortunately also not helpful here, it can only be used to collect statistics, not acquire realtime data as they flow by (see [linux/unix_diag.h](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/uapi/linux/unix_diag.h?h=v4.2-rc5)).

Unfortunately there are no perfect tracers at the moment for Unix domain sockets that produce pcaps (to my best knowledge). Ideally there would be a libpcap format that has a header containing the source/dest PID (when available) followed by optional additional data (credentials, file descriptors) and finally the data. Lacking that, the best that can be done is syscall tracing.

---

Additional information (for the interested reader), here are some backtraces (acquired with GDB breaking on `unix_stream_*` and `rbreak packet.c:.`, Linux in QEMU and socat on mainline Linux 4.2-rc5):

```
# echo foo | socat - UNIX-LISTEN:/foo &
# echo bar | socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/foo
unix_stream_sendmsg at net/unix/af_unix.c:1638
sock_sendmsg_nosec at net/socket.c:610
sock_sendmsg at net/socket.c:620
sock_write_iter at net/socket.c:819
new_sync_write at fs/read_write.c:478
__vfs_write at fs/read_write.c:491
vfs_write at fs/read_write.c:538
SYSC_write at fs/read_write.c:585
SyS_write at fs/read_write.c:577
entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath at arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S:186

unix_stream_recvmsg at net/unix/af_unix.c:2210
sock_recvmsg_nosec at net/socket.c:712
sock_recvmsg at net/socket.c:720
sock_read_iter at net/socket.c:797
new_sync_read at fs/read_write.c:422
__vfs_read at fs/read_write.c:434
vfs_read at fs/read_write.c:454
SYSC_read at fs/read_write.c:569
SyS_read at fs/read_write.c:562

# tcpdump -i lo &
# echo foo | socat - TCP-LISTEN:1337 &
# echo bar | socat - TCP-CONNECT:127.0.0.1:1337
tpacket_rcv at net/packet/af_packet.c:1962
dev_queue_xmit_nit at net/core/dev.c:1862
xmit_one at net/core/dev.c:2679
dev_hard_start_xmit at net/core/dev.c:2699
__dev_queue_xmit at net/core/dev.c:3104
dev_queue_xmit_sk at net/core/dev.c:3138
dev_queue_xmit at netdevice.h:2190
neigh_hh_output at include/net/neighbour.h:467
dst_neigh_output at include/net/dst.h:401
ip_finish_output2 at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:210
ip_finish_output at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:284
ip_output at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:356
dst_output_sk at include/net/dst.h:440
ip_local_out_sk at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:119
ip_local_out at include/net/ip.h:119
ip_queue_xmit at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:454
tcp_transmit_skb at net/ipv4/tcp_output.c:1039
tcp_write_xmit at net/ipv4/tcp_output.c:2128
__tcp_push_pending_frames at net/ipv4/tcp_output.c:2303
tcp_push at net/ipv4/tcp.c:689
tcp_sendmsg at net/ipv4/tcp.c:1276
inet_sendmsg at net/ipv4/af_inet.c:733
sock_sendmsg_nosec at net/socket.c:610
sock_sendmsg at net/socket.c:620
sock_write_iter at net/socket.c:819
new_sync_write at fs/read_write.c:478
__vfs_write at fs/read_write.c:491
vfs_write at fs/read_write.c:538
SYSC_write at fs/read_write.c:585
SyS_write at fs/read_write.c:577
entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath at arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S:186

tpacket_rcv at net/packet/af_packet.c:1962
dev_queue_xmit_nit at net/core/dev.c:1862
xmit_one at net/core/dev.c:2679
dev_hard_start_xmit at net/core/dev.c:2699
__dev_queue_xmit at net/core/dev.c:3104
dev_queue_xmit_sk at net/core/dev.c:3138
dev_queue_xmit at netdevice.h:2190
neigh_hh_output at include/net/neighbour.h:467
dst_neigh_output at include/net/dst.h:401
ip_finish_output2 at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:210
ip_finish_output at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:284
ip_output at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:356
dst_output_sk at include/net/dst.h:440
ip_local_out_sk at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:119
ip_local_out at include/net/ip.h:119
ip_queue_xmit at net/ipv4/ip_output.c:454
tcp_transmit_skb at net/ipv4/tcp_output.c:1039
tcp_send_ack at net/ipv4/tcp_output.c:3375
__tcp_ack_snd_check at net/ipv4/tcp_input.c:4901
tcp_ack_snd_check at net/ipv4/tcp_input.c:4914
tcp_rcv_state_process at net/ipv4/tcp_input.c:5937
tcp_v4_do_rcv at net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c:1423
tcp_v4_rcv at net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c:1633
ip_local_deliver_finish at net/ipv4/ip_input.c:216
ip_local_deliver at net/ipv4/ip_input.c:256
dst_input at include/net/dst.h:450
ip_rcv_finish at net/ipv4/ip_input.c:367
ip_rcv at net/ipv4/ip_input.c:455
__netif_receive_skb_core at net/core/dev.c:3892
__netif_receive_skb at net/core/dev.c:3927
process_backlog at net/core/dev.c:4504
napi_poll at net/core/dev.c:4743
net_rx_action at net/core/dev.c:4808
__do_softirq at kernel/softirq.c:273
do_softirq_own_stack at arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S:970
```

Comment: By the way, if you have read https://kristrev.github.io/2013/07/26/passive-monitoring-of-sockets-on-linux/ and saw instructions to watch for link up notifications via netlink and wondered whether the diagnostics can provide packet sniffing, the answer is still *no*. These diagnostics provide statistics via polling, not realtime.

Comment: `man strace`, `--trace-fds`: "Trace  only  the syscalls that operate on the specified subset of (non-negative) file descriptors.  Note that usage of this option also filters out all the syscalls that do not operate on file descriptors at all." `--read` and `--write` give nice output. I usually use all three mentioned parameters together.

Answer (score 24):

I wrote a [tool](https://github.com/mechpen/sockdump) to capture and dump unix domain socket traffic.  It uses `bpf/kprobe` to probe kernel function `unix_stream_sendmsg` and dump traffic to user space.

The tool depends on [`bcc`](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc), so you need to install `bcc` first.

An example run:

```
$ sudo ./sockdump.py /var/run/docker.sock # run "docker ps" in another terminal
>>> docker[3412] len 83
GET /_ping HTTP/1.1
Host: docker
User-Agent: Docker-Client/18.06.1-ce (linux)

>>> dockerd[370] len 215
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Api-Version: 1.38
Docker-Experimental: false
Ostype: linux
Server: Docker/18.06.1-ce (linux)
Date: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 07:05:03 GMT
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

OK
...
```

Comment: Out of date as of 5.15.0-18 kernel. There are build errors: undeclared `bpf_timer` and `BPF_F_BROADCAST`, Builds when adding the declarations directly to the code but doesn't show any output.

Comment: @Velkan It seems like mechpen patched this. Working for me on 6.3.5-zen1-1-zen

Comment: great tool! worked for me on `6.1.0-18-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.76-1 (2024-02-01) x86_64 GNU/Linux`