# How do command line clipboard tools like "xclip" and "xsel" persist the clipboard - in a X windows environment that doesn't?

Tags: clipboard, x-server

After reading this question about [the X clipboard getting cleared when vim is exited](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3769/can-vim-add-to-the-x11-clipboard-or-primary-buffers-without-an-external-utility) I learned that the X window clipboard only exists while the program - from which the selection was obtained - remains open.
It is because of this behaviour that programs like "glipper" and "parcellite" exist.

If the X clipboard is cleared every time a program is exited, how do programs like `xclip` and `xsel` work?
And what are the security implications of using programs like this? For example, if a password was copied to the clipboard, could this password be saved into some temp file that could be accessed by programs or users?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless there's a clipboard application like `xclipboard`, `clipit`... that steals the selections from them, `xsel`/`xclip` will fork a background process to handle the future selection requests as long as they own the selection.

```
$ printf test | xclip
$ ps -C xclip
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14115 pts/10   00:00:00 xclip
```

That `xclip` process is handling requests for the selection (here PRIMARY selection). But, if you select something in another application (or use `xsel` or `xclip` again to store something else), then that `xclip` process will concede the selection to that other application and terminate.

```
$ printf test | xsel
$ ps -C xclip
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
$ ps -C xsel
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14212 ?        00:00:00 xsel
```

Above, `xsel` took over the selection from `xclip`.

You can find out who owns a given selection with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Display *d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window w = XGetSelectionOwner(d, XInternAtom (d, argv[1], False));
    printf("0x%08x\n", w);
    return 0;
}
```

Then:

```
$ make xgo LDFLAGS=-lX11
$ ./xgo PRIMARY
0x07000001
```

That will give you the window ID. You can use `xprop -id` or `xwininfo -id` on that id, but in the case of `xclip`/`xsel`, you won't get much information.

On GNU/Linux based systems, `ltrace` is useful to see what's happening at the X library API level.

See also [Capture the X11 protocol's traffic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/192005) to see what's happening at the X11 protocol level.

Comment: thanks that explains it. yes a command like `ps -efl --forest` will show `xclip` disowned from its parent and re-attached higher up in the process tree similar to a daemon.  Note to future readers who want to run this c code on ubuntu 16.04, I needed to `sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`, and compile with `gcc -o clip clip.c  -lX11` to avoid make errors.