# how can I parse tcpdump stream live?

Tags: networking, command-line, tcpdump

I have a debian installation, where the OEM has a bunch of processes I dont recognize running, and I want to figure out if any of these things are dialing home.

I ran `sudo tcpdump | grep ^e <ssh_ip>`

but the pipe keeps breaking. I am connected via ssh, and the grep ^e is to omit the ssh ip of my client. Is there a way to continuously monitor the network connection for outbound requests? I don't know that this thing dials home, or where specifically that is,  I just suspect that it does, from other behaviour not related to this question.

broken pipe usualy means the connection breaks, but my ssh connection is fine, it seems to be something else todo with tcpdump

Comment: If the point is to filter out the ssh traffic Why not `tcpdump 'not (host <ssh_ip> and port ssh)'`?

Comment: To filter out an IP address with `grep`, the syntax would rather be `grep -vFw 10.11.12.13`. `grep ^e` assuming a shell where `^` is not treated specially greps for lines that start with the `e` character. If grepping `tcpdump`'s output, you'll likely want to add the `-l` option to `tcpdump` for line buffering.

Comment: wireshark/tshark. SSL traffic cannot be decrypted anyways unless you wanna MITM it by installing/using/forcing your own certificate.

Comment: You can also strace the processes to see what they're doing including what they're sending. See also [How to trace networking activity of a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/375387)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas there are so many processes, strace seems like the nightmare option

Comment: Im trying to recall, isnt there a parser in tcpdump? bfp or something...

Comment: strace can get you one strace file per thread/process with `-ffo prefix`. See also [Capture the X11 protocol's traffic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/192011) for how to decode strace traces into pcap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In:

> ```
> sudo tcpdump | grep ^e <ssh_ip>
> ```

First, that `^e` has different meanings depending on the shell.

- in the Bourne shell, `^` is an alias for `|` (`^`, originally rendered
  more like `↑` being the pipe operator in its predecessor, the Thompson shell), so you'd pipe `grep` to `e` command there.
- in `fish` versions up to 3.2, `^` was to redirect stderr (short for `2>`).
- in `rc` and derivatives, `^` is a sort of concatenation operator so `grep ^e` would become `grepe`.
- in `zsh -o extendedglob`, `^` is a negation glob operator, so `^e` would expand to all the non-hidden files in the current directory other than the one called `e`.
- in `csh`/`tcsh`/`bash`/`zsh`, `^` is only special at the start of the line and only when history expansion is not disabled. So not here.
- in most other shells, `^e` would be passed literally to `grep`.

So assuming one of those latter shells, that command would start `sudo tcpdump` and `grep ^e <ssh_ip>` concurrently with the output of one connected to the input of the other via a pipe.

The syntax of `grep` arguments is `grep [<options>] <regular-expression> [<files>]` (`[...]` indicating optional parts). If there's no file, `grep` greps its stdin¹. Options start with the `-` character.

So here `^e` is the regular-expression, and `<ssh_ip>` is the file to look for lines matching that regexp into.

As a regexp, `^e` matches the start of the line followed by `e`, so that reports lines starting with `e`.

Here, most likely the `<ssh_ip>` file doesn't exist so `grep` will return immediately with an error.

At that point, `tcpdump`'s stdout, inherited from `sudo`'s will become a broken pipe, so the first time `tcpdump` tries to output something, it will receive a SIGPIPE signal and die or if it ignores that signal, its `write()` will fail with a `EPIPE` error. Here, tcpdump managing to write an error message suggests it either ignores that signal and it reports its failing `write()`, or it has a handler on it and reports its reception before terminating.

If you wanted to filter out the lines containing an IP address from the output of `tcpdump`, you'd rather need `grep -Fvw <ssh_ip>` where `-F`, `-v` and `-w` here bundled together in a single argument and are respectively for

- matching on `F`ixed strings rather than a regexp (for `.` to match a literal `.` rather than any single character as it does in regexps).
- re`v`erse the match: return the lines that **don't** match.
- matching on `w`ords only, (to not find `<ssh_ip>` == `10.10.10.10` in `210.10.10.109` for instance).

By default, when tcpdump detects that its output doesn't go to a terminal it reverts to block buffering, so if you want to see the output as soon as it comes, you'd likely want to add the `-l` option to tcpdump to reenable *line* buffering.

But in any case, tcpdump can filter packets by itself. Here, to exclude the packets from/to a given IP address, you just need:

```
sudo tcpdump not host <ssh_ip>
```

Or to only filter out the ssh traffic from that IP address:

```
sudo tcpdump 'not (host <ssh_ip> and tcp port ssh)'
```

(assuming the ssh connection is on the default port 22).

Those filters (Berkeley Packet Filters, BPF) are compiled into a binary filter expression passed to the kernel (`setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ATTACH_FILTER, filter)` on Linux at least). The filtering is happening there, so it's actually less work for tcpdump and the system in general than if tcpdump asked for all traffic, decoded all of it and passed it to grep.

`wireshark`, and its command line interface `tshark` is a much more advanced traffic analysing application which you may want to consider here as well. They support two types of filter: the BPF one as above called *capture filter* (passed with `-f`) and a *display filter* (passed with `-Y`) further applied on the packets returned by the kernel using wireshark's own filter syntax and more advanced capabilities.

---

<sup>¹ or recursively into the current working directory if the `-r`/`-R` options are given in recent versions of the GNU implementation of `grep`.</sup>